# Civi forms in Joomla module (qfKey?)

Tags: joomla, forms, modules

I am trying to put a "mailing list" subscribe form into a Joomla module (having the sign-up be its own page is not very useful).

However, I am running into problems with qfKey. How can I generate a qfKey?

I can copy and paste the generated form html, but submissions can't happen without a valid qfKey in the form post.

Any other/better ways of doing this or is there a simple function I can call to generate a qfKey for mailing list sign up?

Thanks in advance,
Joel

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can generate a qfKey - if I understand your question, using an html-snippet of a Profile that is set up with the Groups field may give you what you want.

Comment: I would like to display newsletter subscriptions in Joomla modules.

If I use a profile, the user will get added to the group, but I don't think they will receive a double opt-in.

Comment: Double opt-in is a setting in civicrm at Admin > CiviMail > CiviMail component Settings - look for "Enable Double Opt-in for Profile Group(s) field"